# Error in Count(),Group by and Joins in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

the result is very different when i separated statements...

```
SELECT Company.CompanyID,
Count(Projects2.CompanyID) as TotalProjects,
Count(Jobs2.CompanyID) as TotalJobs,
Count(Employees.CompanyID) as TotalEmployess
FROM Company JOIN
Projects2 ON Company.CompanyID = Projects2.CompanyID  
JOIN Company Employees ON Company.CompanyID = Employees.CompanyID 
JOIN Company Jobs2 ON Jobs2.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
Group by Company.CompanyID
```

the result

[image]

why repeat the values?
any ideas?

Comment: Because it's a count of the projects, jobs, and employees for each company?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: what do you mean by  `when i separated statements`

Comment: mean that: select Count(id) as emps from Employees
where CompanyID = 38

Comment: Why are you joinning the company table twice and call them "Employees" and "Jobs2". Did you really mean that?

Comment: You need to be joining on other tables using the  company, for example --> INNER JOIN Employees E ON E.CompanyID=Company.CompanyID

Comment: I remove company before table 'emplyee' , jobs... and I get new result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are counting the wrong ID. What is the primary key for the projects2, jobs2 and employees tables? Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT Company.CompanyID,
COUNT(DISTINCT Projects2.Primary_Key) as TotalProjects,
COUNT(DISTINCT Jobs2.Primary_Key) as TotalJobs,
COUNT(DISTINCT Employees.Primary_Key) as TotalEmployees
FROM Company
LEFT JOIN Projects2 ON Company.CompanyID = Projects2.CompanyID  
LEFT JOIN Employees ON Company.CompanyID = Employees.CompanyID 
LEFT JOIN Jobs2 ON Company.CompanyID = Jobs2.CompanyID 
GROUP BY Company.CompanyID
```

Also, use LEFT joins instead of just JOIN and you don't need to keep repeating Company.

The reason you are getting the same count for each table is because of your joins. Say there are five records in the projects table with a given company ID but there are only three records in the jobs table with that ID. When you join company table to the project table you will have five records. Then when you join the jobs table, your joined table will have 15 (5*3) records for that company ID, because each job record will join to each of the five project records. Hence, you only want to select the distinct records from each table, using their primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is joining to the Company table 3 times (aliasing it as Employees and Jobs2 in the later instances). Just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the same values in each of the columns "TotalProjects", "TotalJobs", and "TotalEmployees", because your JOIN (in the future consider using INNER JOIN instead, as it does the same thing but is clearer) is producing results in which there are matching values across the joined tables - so you will end up with a like number of each result.

Comment: So what should to do ??

Comment: Clarify your question, and maybe give an example of some sample data and the result you're expecting.